# Is it possible to search for something specific in the output of an outside executable file using python?

Tags: python, executable

I am writing a code that is using an outside executable file and i am trying to see if there is a way I can search through the output for information that only corresponds with a specific date I provide. The executable file is tsk_gettimes and I am needing to scan through all of the information of the provided file given by a user where the user can just input a date they would like to search for and the code only prints out that information rather than all the information of that file.

```
import os, sys, re

#user file input
filename = input()

if(filename = NULL)
 print(os.system('"C:\\Program Files\\sleuthkit-4.11.1-win32\\bin\\tsk_gettimes.exe"'))


#user date input
keydate = input()

#executable file
os.chdir('C:\\Program Files\\sleuthkit-4.11.1-win32\\bin')
os.system('"C:\\Program Files\\sleuthkit-4.11.1-win32\\bin\\tsk_gettimes.exe %s"', filename).read()

#search for key date
for in
re.search()

#date specifier
```

this is the code i have so far if this helps.

Comment: What file?  It looks like you executing a program and trying to read it's output...

Comment: You cannot search for information in .exe file, because such files compiled and binary, meaning it does not contain any human readable data. That being said, looks like you don't want to search in an exe itself, but in it's **output**, which is very different and much more possible. If that is the case, you might want to edit and clarify your question.

Comment: The program name and argument shouldn't be inside quotes.

Comment: If you want to read the output of the program use `subprocess.Popen()`, not `os.system()`.

Comment: @matszwecja Yes, that is what I meant to say. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: @Barmar When i tried to run the code to see if the executable file was in the code (because i thought i was on the right path) it kept giving error about the spaces. I had seen something on stack overflow that this was a way to fix the error and it worked.

Comment: @alexpdev yes, that is exactly what i am trying to do. I just fixed my question post as i accidently left that part out. Thank you!

Comment: `os.system()` only takes one argument. I don't see how it could work the way you've written it. Use an f-string or formatting function to substitute the filename into the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this... I am not super convinced it will work though without knowing what your executable does.

```
import subprocess
import os

filename, keydate = input().split(' ')

print(filename)
assert os.path.exists(filename)  #  can't find filename
assert os.path.exists("C:\\Program Files\\sleuthkit-4.11.1-win32\\bin\\tsk_gettimes.exe") # can't find executable

prog = subprocess.run([
    "C:\\Program Files\\sleuthkit-4.11.1-win32\\bin\\tsk_gettimes.exe", 
    filename
    ], stdout=subrocess.PIPE)

output = prog.stdout.decode().split('\n')

for i in output:
    if keydate in i:
        print(i)
```

If you get an encoding error just put `latin-1` as an argument to `decode`.
`output = prog.stdout.decode('latin-1').split('\n')`

---

Or try this if you prefer to continue to use `os.system`:

```
import os, sys, re
# user file input

# user date input
keydate = input()

filename = input()
temp = "temp"
with open(temp,'wt') as tempfile:
    pass

temp = f'"{os.path.abspath(temp)}"'

filename = f'{filename}'

#executable file
os.system(f'"C:\\Program Files\\sleuthkit-4.11.1-win32\\bin\\tsk_gettimes.exe" {filename} >> {temp_location}')
with open(temp_location,'rt') as temp:
    data = temp.read()

os.remove(temp_location)

#search for key date
for i in data.split('\n'):
    if keydate in i:
        print(i)
```

Comment: The executable file prints out all the information of the file given (like a .dd file) For example, if i input a (.dd) file it would return when the drive was used and what time and day each action occurred on the drive. Hopefully that makes sense. What i am trying to do is read through the output of the (.dd) file, for example, and only pull out the information that correspondes with the date

Comment: @studyhard did you try the approach above?  did the oupt print properly?

Comment: thats what a dd file is, yes. As for the code, it's giving me an error when adding a file into the terminal saying it is not existing but the file is on my computer.

Comment: which file?  the temp file?

Comment: @studyhard  I was able to get the above code working for me.  See if that workls

Comment: "Error stat(ing) image file (raw_open: image "FOREINSICS\temp" - No such file or directory" This is my error

Comment: @studyhard you must have spaces in your file path.  I put quotes around that portion.  Try it now with the edits

Comment: "'C:\\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file" This the error it gave, this was the problem i was having before and i added the os.chdir but that doesnt seem to work either

Comment: @studyhard Its because you have spaces in your paths...  try it now, hopefully that fixes it.  the chdir is unneccessary

Comment: "i" is needing bytes but i need a string because the date i have is  in hex "1092955220"

Comment: can you create a gist with your current source code  or just copy and paste the whole thing into your question?  or pastebin.  because both the examples above work fine for me.  And i am using a string for the date as well.  If you have a github account a gist is probably the better option.

Comment: import subprocess

# user file input
filename = input()

# user date input
keydate = input()

#reading the output of the executable file
test = subprocess.run(["C:\\Program Files\\sleuthkit-4.11.1-win32\\bin\\tsk_gettimes.exe", filename],
   stdout = subprocess.PIPE)

output = test.stdout.decode().split('\n')

#retreiving all the matches of the keydate
for i in output:
    if keydate in i:
        print(i)

#keydate converted to UNIX Hex "Error stat(ing) image file (raw_open: image "" - No such file or directory)" i fixed the string error

Comment: either that or the .dd file i have been trying to use

Comment: @studyhard So it's still having trouble with your paths.... try adding `assert os.file.exists(filename)` after the you get the input for the filename. you can do the same thing for the executable too.   I edited my answer for examples

Comment: @studyhard if it works from the command line then there is no reason for it not to work this way.

Comment: @studyhard  I mean `os.path.exists(filename)` not `file`  sorry

Comment: "assert os.path.exists(filename)
AssertionError" do you think if i make the code an executable itself and then run the life after that, it will work?

Comment: No i dont think that would work... however you are inputing the pathname is not working...  try this so you can see how your input looks inside the program.

Comment: interesting.... It printed out the file name and the information needed from the executable. what i did differently was put my values in a separate times...

Comment: yes, is there a way i can just give my values at the same time?

Comment: @studyhard sure try it now.... they need to be seperated by a space though

Answer (score 2):

Use `subprocess.popen()` to run a command and read its output.

```
import subprocess

with subprocess.Popen(['C:\\Program Files\\sleuthkit-4.11.1-win32\\bin\\tsk_gettimes.exe', filename], stdout=PIPE) as proc:
    output = proc.stdout.read()

if re.search(regexp, output):
    ...
```

Comment: I like this answer because it uses subprocess.Popen( ) which, unlike os.system( ) (or os.popen( ) does not start up an external shell (such as bash) to run the command which makes it inherently safer.

Comment: @barmar this wouldn't this throw an error?  I dont think the interpreter would know what PIPE is.

Comment: Python knows how to implement it on Windows.